# Why similar queries show vastly different performance using DolphinDB Python API?

Tags: python, performance, query-optimization, dolphindb

I use 2 different methods to query data in DolphinDB Python API. The first one uses the `loadTableBySQL` method, and the second uses the `select` method:

```
s_db=np.datetime64(start_date.replace('.','-'))
e_db=np.datetime64(end_date.replace('.','-')) 
s=time.time()

#method 1: 0.017m
stk_price = session.loadTableBySQL(tableName="KdayA11", dbPath="dfs://kline",sql=r"select * from KdayAll where trade_dt>={s},trade_dt<={e}".format(s=start_date,e=end_date)) 

#method 2: 0.00018m
tb=session.loadTable(tableName="KdayA11", dbPath="dfs://kline") 
session.upload({'s_db':s_db})
session.upload({'e_db':e_db})
stk_price=tb.select("*").where('trade_dt>-s_db').where('trade_dt<=e_db') 
e=time.time()
```

Why does the second method exhibit better performance by 100 times than the first?

Comment: Shouldn't `>-` be `>=`?

Comment: is it possible that some caching comes into play? Have you tried running first method2, then method1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, neither of the methods retrieves data from DolphinDB server because you need to use `toDF()` to download the result from server to Python.

In your script, method 1 uses `loadTableBySQL` to execute the query on the server side but does not download the result; while method 2 only concatenates the script which is actually not executed. That’s why the 2 methods show such performance difference.